# Can't average multiple IF formulas

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have in cell c3 the formula

```
=IF(c2<4,"4",IF(c2=4,"3",IF(c2=5,"2",IF(c2=6,"1",IF(c2>6,"0")))))
```

if the contents of c2 is 5, then the answer in c3 will be 2. Everything is OK up to here.

These formulas occur in a spreadsheet every 40 rows, so in a spreadsheet with over 6000 rows, there is a lot of calculations. I wish to average the cell contents of all of these figures eg c42, c82, c122, c162, etc

I wish to average these multiple formulas. However in cell c1, the formula

```
=AVERAGEIF($B:$B,"stableford (blue)",C:C)
```

the result is #DIV/0. For some reason, the cell c1 cant average out multiple IF.... results. 
Is there a way to correct the answer in c1 and calculate an average figure rather than get the error

Comment: "For some reason the cell c1 cant average out multiple IF.... results" - the issue is not that it's result of the IF formula, the issue is that those results are texts, don't convert them to text (e.g. use `4` instead of `"4"`). Also some sample data would help us to understand your question better.

Comment: thanks for your assistance. The best solution for me that I have tested and works is the first formula, which is to remove the text format i.e " " out of the formula. this seems to work for me and will calculate the IF averages that I want

Answer (score 1):

Use formula like

```
=AVERAGE(IF(MOD(ROW(C40:C6000),40)=2,C40:C6000))
```

Press CTRL + SHIFT + ENTER from within the formula bar to create an Array Formula. The formula shall be enclosed in curly braces to indicate that it's an array formula.

If you wish to start with C2 then replace C40 with C2 in the above formula.

In above formula you should be particular about last cell in the column. e.g. if your last cell is 5500 and you enter C40:C6000 then wherever applicable, zeros could get added altering the average.

Comment: just a comment on that second formula - OR only returns a single result, not an array, so typically, like AND, it doesn't work as expected in these formulas. If any one cell meets any condition then all values will be averaged, so because some of the MOD(ROW conditions will always be met that formula will always give you the same as just =AVERAGE(C2:C6000)

Comment: @barry houdini you are right, it slipped off my mind somehow! It's removed.Thanks

Comment: Hi Pat   thanks for your assistance. The best solution for me that I have tested and works is the first formula, which is to remove the text format i.e " " out of the formula. this seems to work for me and will calculate the IF averages that I want

Answer (score 0):

Basically you are looking to calculate the Average of every 40th value in the Column you have applied the Formula.

**For better understanding in place of every 40th I've taken 5th value.**

[image]

In the  second column I've used **your Formula with modification** which is,

=IF(MOD(ROW(),**5**)=1,IF(E616<4,4,IF(E616=4,3,IF(E616=5,2,IF(E616=6,1,IF(E616>6,0))))),"")

**Drag it down till its required.**

And finally I've used Formula which is counting Average of every 5th value is,

{=AVERAGE(IF(MOD(ROW(F616:F626)-ROW(F616),**5**)=0,IF(F616:F626<>"",F616:F626)))}

**NB:** **Formula is in Column F**.

You need to **Replace 5 with 40 in both Formulas**.

Finish the Formula with **Ctrl+Shift+Enter.**

Also change the Data Range as your need.

**Hope this help you, in case it differs  drop comment with your concern.**

Comment: Hi Rajesh thanks for your assistance. The best solution for me that I have tested and works is the first formula, which is to remove the text format  i.e  " " out of the formula. this seems to work for me and will calculate the IF averages that I want

Comment: Nice to hear from you @murray, keep asking.